# Formatting a matlab equation

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write the equation y = Ae^((-b/2m)*t) but for some reason I keep getting an error. I have defined all of my variables and have found that e can be used as a constant. Is this equation correct, or am I doing something wrong?

Update: Nevermind I think I got it, this is what it looks like in Matlab: y = A*exp((-b/(2*m))*t);
I think this is right, but is it the same as the equation y = Ae^((-b/2m)*t)?

Comment: Is your t value an array?

Comment: It would help if you posted the error.

Comment: 2m is laughing at you

Comment: Do you know any Matlab syntax? `Ae^x` is a single variable to the power of `x`, `A*e^x` is `A` multiplied by `e` to power of `x`. Also, `2m` is invalid syntax, if you want a variable called `2m`, you can't, variable names have to start with letters, and if you meant 2 times `m`, then do `2*m`. Read about some language fundamentals here: http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/language-fundamentals.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear from the question what type of error you get but code below should do the deal:

```
t=1:10;
A=2;
b=3;
m=2.5;

y=A*exp(-b/(2*m)*t)
```